# Playing specfic games crashes my computer

Tags: windows-8, crash, gaming

I have noticed this issue once before thinking it was just an issue with the game but now it has happened with several games and it's really annoying me because I can't figure out why it is happening. The crash happens at seemingly random times while I am playing and I'll usually get a blank purple screen (sometimes black) before my PC then restarts. The crashes only happen while playing very specific games and they happen consistently every time I play them, although the time at which the crash occurs is random. I've been unable to find anything on the specific issue I'm having, the closest thing I found was people getting crashes because of an overheating problem which I can definitely say is not the problem since I've been able to play most other games for much longer periods without any issues whatsoever. I've only had this PC for a couple months so it's basically brand new. All my drivers are fully up to date. Any assistance in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

PC:
Asus
Windows 8.1 64 Bit
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
NVidia Geforce GTX 750
16 GB of Ram
2 TB Hard Drive.

I'm using an older PnP monitor from a Windows XP desktop if that makes any difference at all.

Games that have crashed:
Chivalry: Medieval Warfare, SMITE, Grav, Dungeon Defenders 2, Nosgoth.

Edit 1: Event Viewer doesn't show anything out of the ordinary. Checked the temperatures while testing several games including ones that crash. nothing seemed abnormally high.
Edit 2 : All these games are running with direct X 9c. I have no problems with games running direct X 11. perhaps that is issue? and if it is how do I fix it?
Edit 3: Just tried another game Blade and Soul which crashed on me as well. I checked and it is indeed running with direct x 9c. This is pretty well looking like it is the problem but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. Any suggestions? All other versions of Direct X are running without issues.

Comment: Check the event logs for errors. [What information appears in event logs? (Event Viewer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: You should not rule out overheating - it is possible that your GPU is marginal, and only a specific part of it dies when the system gets too hot - this part being a specific instruction called in certain games.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on your explanation please? I'm not understanding fully what you're trying to say.

Comment: Still having the same problem months later? anyone?